# How to find out user’s `sharing` and `security` access rights in c# application

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, directory

I had given read access right of network `shared` folder to other domain user.Now I want to test using c# code particularly `Sharing access rights`.

**How to find out user’s `sharing` and `security` access rights in  c# application?**

**How can .net understand rights are sharing or security related?**

[image]

Comment: If I've understood your situation correctly, you only really need to tell whether the user has read access to the shared directory or not.  If this is true, the simplest solution would probably be to try to list the directory or open a file that is known to exist.  If the attempt fails, the user does not have access.

Comment: @HarryJohnston finally I have implemented solution to test access rights like, create sample file on shared path and check `unauthorized exception`.